# Discord.py mostrar avatar de qualquer id

Tags: python, syntax-error

Bom, eu tenho um comando de avatar e quando eu tento pegar o id de uma pessoa que não esteja no mesmo servidor que o meu bot, e usar o !avatar [id da pessoa que não esteja no mesmo servidor que o meu bot] ele dá esse erro:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound: Member  not found.
```

e eu queria que ele mostrasse o avatar de qualquer pessoa que não esteja no mesmo servidor que o bot.
Meu código:

```
@commands.command()
    async def avatar(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
        if user == None:
            user = ctx.author
        else:
            if user == None:
                user = ctx.author

                avatar2Embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user.name}\nClique no icon/gif para baixá-lo.', description= f'Ou clique [aqui]({user.avatar_url_as})', timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color=discord.Color.dark_blue())
                avatar2Embed.set_image(url=f'{user.avatar_url_as}')

                await ctx.send(embed=avatar2Embed)


        icon_url = user.avatar_url
        avatarEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user.name}\nClique no icon/gif para baixá-lo.', description= f'Ou clique [aqui]({user.avatar_url})', timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color=discord.Color.dark_blue())
        avatarEmbed.set_image(url=f'{icon_url}')
        await ctx.send(embed=avatarEmbed)
```

Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço.

(Eu sei que ficou meio complicado essa explicação, mas eu posso explicar melhor nos comentários caso alguém não entenda)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o objeto que você está retornando é um discord.Member, o que você quer é um discord.User. Além disso quando você utiliza o comando você está passando uma string e não o usuário propriamente dito, para isso você tem que usar o método: `Bot.fetch_user(id)`

Por fim existe um erro na lógica, no caso do else você está verificando o mesmo do if, portanto é impossível o código executar caso `user != None`.

Reescrevendo o código para algo funcional:

```py
@commands.command()
    async def avatar(self, ctx, userid: int = None):
        if userid == None:
            user = ctx.author
        else:
            user = bot.fetch_user(userid)

        icon_url = user.avatar_url
        avatarEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user.name}\nClique no icon/gif para baixá-lo.', description= f'Ou clique [aqui]({user.avatar_url})', timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color=discord.Color.dark_blue())
        avatarEmbed.set_image(url=f'{icon_url}')
        await ctx.send(embed=avatarEmbed)
```

Comment: Ajudou muito, mas teve um probleminha de 'coroutine' no avatar_url, porém acrescentei o "await" na frente do user, e funcionou corretamente. Obrigado!

Comment: Por nada, se puder marcar como resposta, agradeço.